# VS update broke the microsoft.analytics.dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have a solution with two projects (C# and U-SQL) to run in the Azure Data Factory. I have referenced microsoft.analytics to use some analytics functions.

After the VS update to 15.9.14 on July 9, 2019 the c# project was not building giving the error that the assembly is missing but it was not missing. If I clicked to the error it go away and recognize the assembly. Then I try to build again and same error appears.

So I check the dll and the version was the same as before update but after I opened it with dotPeek I saw that the assembly target framework was changed to 4.7.2.

My project is on 4.5 because of the **official azure data factory documentation** says that we **can run projects only up to framework 4.5** so I can't upgrade to 4.7 or above.

You can see the difference of those dll. 
[image]

*Assemblies location:*

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies

So to resolve the problem I froze those dll and added as external references to my project in order to compile and build it and it worked.

If I want to create a new U-SQL project I can only pick 4.7.2.
[image]

My question is, how I can **run U-SQL projects** and analytics assemblies on an framework that is still **not supported** in the azure data lake?
If the Data Lake now supports **4.7.2** why there is no documentation for it or at least something to let us know?
Is this an VS minor update with a **bug**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some Microsoft tickets they don't know how to respond to this. They said to try run some methods that are only present in the 4.7.2 framework in the data lake.
So I tried those methods and the jobs didn't run for obvious reasons.

**Conclusion:**

- VS migrated the U-SQL projects to 4.7.2 but we can't run custom c# code for this target framework in the Azure.
- Data Lake Analytics runs only 4.5 as said in documentation.

For now our project  will remain 4.5.